# Oracle to MySQL with SQLines: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, oracle, database-migration

I need to migrate data from a large Oracle table (8.5 million rows) to MySQL. From forum searches, SQLines seemed to be the best option.

However, when I run my data transfer, I get the following error:

```
Transferring database (1 session):

  USER.TABLE - Started (1 of 1, session 1)
  USER.TABLE - Open cursor (5342 rows read, 63 ms, session 1)
  USER.TABLE - Drop target table (47 ms, session 1)
  USER.TABLE - Create target table (46 ms, session 1)
  USER.TABLE - Data transfer failed
    Lost connection to MySQL server during query
     Rows read:     5342 (84794 rows/sec)
     Rows written:  0 (0 rows/sec, 0 bytes, 0 bytes/sec)
     Transfer time: 297 ms (63 ms read, 0 ms write)

Failed tables (1 table):

    1. USER.TABLE - Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

The very strange thing is that it happens immediately, even before any timeout can occur. Based on tips on a similar error (outside of SQLines), I've tried setting max_allowed_packet to 64M, but that didn't make a difference.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What do the MySQL logs say?

Comment: Not much I'm afraid. Neither the error nor the general log show anything helpful.